# Programming in C using pipes to send info backwards

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to figure out how to use pipes. I've managed to set up pipes to send information from C1 (child 1) to C2 (child 2) however, when I try to do the opposite e.g. sending an integer "10" from C2 to C1 it gets stuck after my first `system("ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm")` call. In general I don't seem to have problem sending stuff forward however problem seems to  arise when I try to do stuff backwards. Am I missing some logical steps here?

./in reads an integer and prints it and ./out takes an integer and writes it. They seems to be working perfectly okay.

```
 #include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int main()
{
int fds[2];
pid_t pid;
int test;

if(pipe(fds)<0)
{
    exit(0);
}

pid = fork();

if(pid==0)
{//C1
    test = close(READ); assert(test==0);
    test = dup(fds[READ]); assert(test==READ);
    test = close(fds[READ]); assert(test==0);
    test = close(fds[WRITE]); assert(test==0);
    sleep(1);
    execlp("./in", "./in", NULL);
    exit(1);
}
system("ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm");
wait(0);
system("ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm");
sleep(2);
pid = fork();

if(pid==0)
{//C2
    test = close(WRITE); assert(test==0);
    test = dup(fds[WRITE]); assert(test==WRITE);
    test = close(READ); assert(test==0);
    test = close(fds[READ]); assert(test==0);
    test = close(fds[WRITE]); assert(test==0);
    sleep(2);
    execlp("./out", "./out", "10", NULL);
    exit(0);
}
sleep(1);
test = close(fds[READ]); assert(test==0);
test = close(fds[WRITE]); assert(test==0);
system("ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm");
wait(0);
system("ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that pipes are *one way only*. If you want to communicate both ways you need two pipe pairs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude he can use one pipe, but two pipes will be easier. As for the first option he will have to synchronize access to pipe.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I don't really get it, it seems i am only sending something one way? e.g. from C2 to C1? if i just switch the ./in and ./out from C2 to C1 and switch the places of close(write) etc it work perfectly..

Comment: Hi Tony Tannous can you please elaborate on that or give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your process is getting stuck is the `wait()` system call after calling `system()`. `system()` actually calls `wait()` itself so your `wait()` is waiting for child 1 to finish but child 1 is itself probably blocked on IO.

For bidirectional communication, you really need two pipes, one for communication in each direction. With the second pipe you do pretty much exactly what you do at the moment except for child 1 you replace stdout and for child 2 you replace stdin.

Answer (score 0):

the `dup()` function returns a file descriptor.

The child code is overlaying that file descriptor with the returned value from a call to `close()`  Usually the returned value from `close()` is 0, which is NOT a file descriptor.

There is no communication possible via a pipe in the posted code as both end of the pipe are closed before calling `execlp()` for both child 1 and child 2.